# Let $S$:$V$→$W$ and $T$:$V$→$W$ be linear transformations...

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $S$:$V$→$W$ and $T$:$V$→$W$ be linear transformations. Given *a* in  ℝ, define functions $(S+T):V→W$ and (*a*$T$):$V→W$ by $(S+T)$(**v**)=S(**v**)+T(**v**) and (*a*$T$)(**v**)=*a*$T$(**v**) for all **v** in $V$. Show that $S+T$ and *a*$T$ are linear transformations.

Comment: Do you what a linear transformation is? If so, just check the axioms are satisfied for $aT$ and $S+T$. The proof should start by "Let $(x,y)\in V^2$ and $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$, then [...]".

Comment: @C.Falcon In order for something to be a linear transformation it needs to   satisfy the following axioms: 

T1. T(v + v1)=T(v)+T(v1) for all v and v1 in V

T2. T(rv)= rT(v) for all v in V and all r in ℝ

I just don't understand how to actually prove that one or both don't hold.

Comment: Hello, you should always express what you did in your questions.

Comment: @TaljanaD You are right about the definition! You will have hard time showing that either $T_1$ or $T_2$ does not hold. Indeed, $S+T$ and $aT$ are actually linear transformations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll show just one of the two, try to do the other one. Let $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\vec{v},\vec{w}\in V$ so

$$(aT)(\alpha \vec{v}+\beta \vec{w}) = aT(\alpha \vec{v}+\beta \vec{w}) \stackrel{\text{T is linear}}{=}(a\alpha)T(\vec{v})+(a\beta)T(\vec{w})$$

But $(a\alpha),(a\beta)\in \mathbb{R}$. So we can use $a\alpha = \alpha a$.

$$= \alpha(aT)(\vec{v}) + \beta(aT)(\vec{w})$$

So this proofs that $(aT):V\to W$ is a linear transformation. It is fundamental to have that $T$ is a linear transformation. This gives you and idea of how to proced in those cases. Try the other one.